# Android 5 lollipop update remove all AIR apps

Tags: android, air, adobe, android-5.0-lollipop

I updated to Android 5 OTA on two Nexus 7 2013 and 2012, after upgrading all the AIR apps were removed, native apps remained. I tried to install the apps from Google Play and i got an 505 install error. 
The logcat error is below:

E/Finsky(4449): [1] PackageInstallerImpl.handleCommitCallback: Error -505 while installing air.com.123.456 INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/air.com.123.456-1: Package air.com.123.456 signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

The apps are the same as before upgrading , they were not updated, the certificate is the same.

Anyone else seen this problem, is there an AIR patch?

I can install the app by "adb uninstall" command then re installing from Google play.

The problem happens on apps using AIR upto 15.302, some are on AIR 14 still. I have also got the same error reported by a few users who upgraded to 5, also using Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like at the moment just have to wait for Google to release an OTA update to fix the certificate issue nothing can be really done for existing apps .For new apps use the patched ADT from adobe and/or 2048 certificate.

**UPDATE**

Android 5.0.1 OTA update seems to fix the problems

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known issue now. Both [Adobe](https://forums.adobe.com/message/6934105) and [Google](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1668) are working on it. Hopefully.